# Multi-graded hilbert series in sage

Tags: sagemath

Is there a way to compute the multi-graded Hilbert series in sage? I know that one can do it in Macaulay2, see  https://mathoverflow.net/questions/20263/software-for-computing-multi-graded-hilbert-series. But I am wondering whether one can do similarly in sage? I am looking for realization in sage for other reasons that could not be implemented in Macaulay2.